# In codeigniter how can i find data between two dates

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to fetch data between two dates in php

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table_name');
this-> db ->where('t_deadline' between $start_deadline and $end_deadline);
```

but this query not execute.

Comment: Last line should be

$this->db->where('t_deadline between "'.$start_deadline.'" and "'.$end_deadline.'"');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->db->where('order_date >=', $first_date);
$this->db->where('order_date <=', $second_date);
return $this->db->get('orders');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table_name');
$this->db->where('t_deadline >=', $start_deadline);
$this->db->where('t_deadline <=', $end_deadline);
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
print_r($result);
```